# Automating graph.microsoft.com authentication and mailbox reading

Tags: bash, oauth-2.0, outlook

I'm trying to debug a bash script that can be run by Splunk to logon to outlook.com and read the email in my inbox.

I've created the bash script and tested each part by running each line manually.

```
#!/bin/bash
#

#
# Get the mailbox name
#
MAILBOX=$1

#
# Verify the mailbox name
#
case $MAILBOX in
    "mine")
         ;;
    "work1")
         ;;
    "work2")
         ;;
    "work3")
         ;;
    *)
         echo "$1 is not a valid mailbox."
         exit 1
         ;;
esac

#
# Set Globals
#
SLEEP_TIME=600

#
# Export the libraries needed for SSL
#
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64

#
# Set the paths
#
BIN_DIR=/home/splunk/bin
MY_MESSAGES=/apps/data/monitored_mailboxes/${1}

#
# Change directory to where $MY_MESSAGES are
#
cd $MY_MESSAGES

#
# Copy last_read.txt to a back up file and set last_read.txt to the far future so it only sets the token
#
mv last_read.txt last_read_backup.txt
echo "2100-01-01 00:00:00+0000" > last_read.txt

#
# Get the token
#
python ${BIN_DIR}/get_inbox_email.py -l ${MY_MESSAGES}/last_read.txt -t ${MY_MESSAGES}/0365_token.txt

#
# Restore the original last_read.txt
#
mv last_read_backup.txt last_read.txt

#
# Loop the python script
#
while true; do
  #
  # Get the current timestamp
  #
  timestamp=`date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S'`

  #
  # Get the messages if any
  #
  python ${BIN_DIR}/get_inbox_email.py -l ${MY_MESSAGES}/last_read.txt -t ${MY_MESSAGES}/0365_token.txt > ${MY_MESSAGES}/messages/mail_${timestamp}.txt

  #
  # Remove old message files
  #
  find ${MY_MESSAGES}/messages -mtime +7 -print

  #
  # Sleep
  #
  sleep $SLEEP_TIME
done
```

I expect the second python call to use the token created in the first python call, but I'm getting prompted to open the authentication URL again and then paste in the email URL.

Answer (score 0):

Old tired eyes.  I have 0365_token.txt instead of o365_token.txt.  When I replaced that in the bash script I was able to start running it without issues.